# Reading which of the properties of the DOM element can lead to repaint (reflow) page by browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

**Reading** which of the propertie of the DOM element can lead to repaint (reflow) page by browser? (**Property not modified**)

- innerHTML
- style

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

style checking may need to reflow if there are changes pending for a property you request. For example, if you set the width of a parent element, and the child is a 100% of the parent. The reflow will either happen after the JavaScript takes its turn (with the GUI repaint), or immediately if you ask for the child node's width.

innerHTML won't cause a reflow just by reading.